# How to import idautils outside ida pro using python

Tags: python, execute, ida

IDApython works fine within IDA pro in the command line. However, outside IDA pro in a normal editor when I compile the python program with import idautis I get the error:

"No module named _idaapi'

```
from idautils import *
from idaapi import *

ea = BeginEA()
for funcea in Functions(SegStart(ea), SegEnd(ea)):
    functionName = GetFunctionName(funcea)
    functionStart = paddAddr(hex(funcea)[2:])
    functionEnd = paddAddr(hex(FindFuncEnd(funcea))[2:])
   <REST OF THE CODE>
```

how to execute the python code outside IDA pro?

Answer (score 6):

You can't really execute IDAPython scripts outside IDA, but you can make it so IDA is run silent and doesn't display its GUI.

In your scripts, you need to redirect `stdout` to a file, for example :

```
import sys
import idaapi
import idc
import os

def stdout_to_file(output_file_name, output_dir=None):
    '''Set stdout to a file descriptor

    param: output_file_name: name of the file where standard output is written.
    param: output_dir: output directory for output file, default to script directory.

    Returns: output file descriptor, original stdout descriptor
    '''
    # obtain this script path and build output path
    if not output_dir:
        output_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, output_file_name)

    # save original stdout descriptor
    orig_stdout = sys.stdout

    # create output file
    f = file(output_file_path, "w")

    # set stdout to output file descriptor
    sys.stdout = f

    return f, orig_stdout

def main(args):
    # get original stdout and output file descriptor
    f, orig_stdout = stdout_to_file("output.txt")

    if idc.ARGV:
        for i, arg in enumerate(idc.ARGV):
            print "[*] arg[{}]: {}".format(i, arg)

    # call something from IDA (get the original input file name from IDB)
    print "[*] filename from IDB: {}".format(idaapi.get_root_filename())
    print("[*] done, exiting.")

    # restore stdout, close output file
    sys.stdout = orig_stdout 
    f.close()

    # exit IDA
    idc.Exit(0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Then on the command line you can invoke your IDAPython script (assuming IDA is in your PATH):

```
idaq.exe  -A -S"C:\tmp\test_script.py foo bar" "C:\tmp\mydatabase.idb"
```

- `-A` is for running IDA silent
- `-S` is for the script path and the script arguments
- The last argument is the idb path (or use `-t` for generating a temp idb)

Check the IDA help file for a comprehensive list of all available options.

Output, in output.txt file (the IDB was from the input file 'calc.exe'):

```
[*] arg[0]: C:\tmp\test_script.py
[*] arg[1]: foo
[*] arg[2]: bar
[*] filename from IDB: calc.exe
[*] done, exiting.
```

You can also check out the hex ray blog titled "[Running scripts from the command line with idascript](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=128)"